# Cakephp case sensitive controller name causing trouble in my linux hosting

Tags: php, cakephp

I am facing a strange problem. I am new in cakephp so dont have any idea why its happening and how to resolve this.

I have cake installed at my test server [here](http://linkwag.hansoftz.com/)

its running fine in windows hosting and at my local xampp server.

any body having idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: Might just be what you guessed in the title? How do you call the html helper?

Comment: do you know the solution?

Comment: Try changing cases...

Comment: I had tried but, then i will have to change case of all my controllers and helpers..

Comment: `but, then i will have to change case of all my controllers and helpers.` - yep. and the sooner you do, the sooner you won't have problems like this - it's in [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#file-and-classname-conventions).

Answer (score 3):

Windows filesystem is case insensitive while linux and mac are case sensitive. So if you are developing on windows then deploy to linux, if you don't have the correct case for your filenames you will get errors.

Comment: but only in cakephp i am facing such issue and not in any other framework. is there any configuration in cakephp to skip case sensitive names.

Comment: Then you got lucky. This is a very common issue with developing on windows and deploying to linux. This is not the last time you will run into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you will have to change cases to your controllers and helpers. Moreover, if you are using git for your version control, you will have to delete those files, commit, and then add them again!

Developers tend to use linux virtual machines for development in order to avoid such problems (this is one of the few differences between windows and linux machines)

Comment: Your answer is correct and I voted you up but I'll have to disagree that "this is one of the few differences. It is in fact one of the most-known differences however both OSs are very different in architecture, idea, design and concepts.